# Installing Rails engine gem - path not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

I've been following the guide around rails engines here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html and have created the example engine `blorgh` and also have a barebones rails app.

I generated my engine following this command:

`rails plugin new blorgh --mountable`

And I can confirm that I have: `/lib/blorgh.rb` in my engine. Now going by the guides it states you simply need to add the following to your main app:

`gem 'blorgh', path: 'engines/blorgh'`. Now in my main rails app when I try to do `bundle install` I get:

> The path `/Users/home/projects/unicorn/engines/blorgh` does not exist.

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something basic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The path /Users/home/projects/unicorn/engines/blorgh does not exist

Because Rails application going to Search ‘engines’ folder that's stores the engines (even if you just have one!) in your case `/engines/blorgh` not found any engine.

Comment: @green1919 Most Welcome... If this document helps you then share it and vote up so it can be available for more users.

Answer (score 0):

The path option in Gemfile is for using gem that is on the path specified. 
And it have to be the directory where the unpacked gem is located.

In your case it looked to `engines/blorgh` relative to your working directory. Which is on `/Users/home/projects/unicorn/engines/blorgh`.

And `/Users/home/projects/unicorn/engines/blorgh` is simply doesn't exists.

To fix it, make sure you put the engine on `/Users/home/projects/unicorn/engines/blorgh`

Comment: that makes sense, but what do you mean exactly by: 

> make sure you put the engine on /Users/home/projects/unicorn/engines/blorgh

What am I putting in this directory exactly?

Comment: @David the engine, the files for the engine. In this case, the asker is using an engine that is packaged on a gem called `blorgh`.